# How to undo a SQL Server UPDATE query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server Management Studio, I did the query below.
Unfortunately, I forgot to uncomment the `WHERE` clause.
1647 rows were updated instead of 4.

How can I undo the last statement?

Unfortunately, I've only just finished translating those 1647 rows and was doing final corrections <del>, and thus don't have a backup</del>.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[T_Language]
   SET 
       [LANG_DE] = 'Mietvertrag' --<LANG_DE, varchar(255),>
      ,[LANG_FR] = 'Contrat de bail' -- <LANG_FR, varchar(255),>
      ,[LANG_IT] = 'Contratto di locazione' -- <LANG_IT, varchar(255),>      
      ,[LANG_EN] = 'Tenancy agreement' -- <LANG_EN, varchar(255),>
       --WHERE [LANG_DE] like 'Mietvertrag'
```

There is a transaction protocol, at least I hope so.

Comment: Have you ever taken a backup? What is your recovery model set to?

Comment: Oh thank god, I have an automatic backup from today afternoon.

Comment: `SELECT name,recovery_model_desc FROM sys.databases`

Comment: name -> CENSORED, recovery_model_desk -> FULL

Comment: You also need to check that the database isn't in `auto_truncate` mode (it doesn't sound like it will be  which is good!) `SELECT name,recovery_model_desc, CASE WHEN last_log_backup_lsn IS NULL THEN 'On' ELSE 'Off' END as AutoTruncate FROM sys.databases d join sys.database_recovery_status r ON r.database_id=d.database_id` Assuming that this is the case then you should be good to use your backup and do a point in time restore (do this as a new database to be safe). More details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982.aspx

Comment: Thanks, no it isn't in AutoTruncate -> OFF

Comment: Interesting defaults, looks like somebody already made the experience.

Comment: [Good answer here: If you're in FULL recovery then you can use SSMS to restore to point-in-time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16945254/2662901).  Now, why you can't undo a specific transaction, especially in an SSMS session, I would like to know....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A non-committed transaction can be reverted by issuing the command `ROLLBACK`

But if you are running in auto-commit mode there is nothing you can do....

Comment: Not true - Point in time recovery might be available via the transaction logs dependant on the OP's recovery model and whether they have ever taken a backup.

Comment: Agreed, looking at the comments seems the OP was lucky anyway!

Answer (score 18):

If you already have a full backup from your database, fortunately, you have an option in SQL Management Studio. In this case, you can use the following steps:

1. Right click on database -> Tasks -> Restore -> Database.
2. In General tab, click on Timeline -> select Specific date and time option.
3. Move the timeline slider to before update command time -> click OK.
4. In the destination database name, type a new name.
5. In the Files tab, check in Reallocate all files to folder and then select a new path to save your recovered database.
6. In the options tab, check in Overwrite ... and remove Take tail-log... check option.
7. Finally, click on OK and wait until the recovery process is over.

I have used this method myself in an operational database and it was very useful.

Answer (score 5):

Considering that you already have a full backup I’d just restore that backup into separate database and migrate the data from there.

If your data has changed after the latest backup then what you recover all data that way but you can try to recover that by reading transaction log.

If your database was in full recovery mode than transaction log has enough details to recover updates to your data after the latest backup.

You might want to try with DBCC LOG, fn_log functions or with third party log reader such as [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)

Unfortunately there is no easy way to read transaction log because MS doesn’t provide documentation for this and stores the data in its proprietary format.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a FULL backup, you can restore the backup to a different server as a database of the same name or to the same server with a different name.

Then you can just review the contents pre-update and write a SQL script to do the update.

Comment: It won't be necessary, I realized, I made an update-script about 2 hours ago (hadn't saved it however, and wanted to discard it - luckily hadn't yet done so.). I updated all values, and have only made 4 changes since (which i remember), so I have not lost more than 5 minutes work. Wow, I'm one hell of a lucky guy...

Answer (score 0):

If you can catch this in time and you don't have the ability to `ROLLBACK` or use the transaction log, you can take a backup immediately and use a tool like [Redgate's SQL Data Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to generate a script to "restore" the affected data.  This worked like a charm for me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a good way to undo or recovery databases using SQL Server Manager. by following the below points :

1 - Go to Database from left side -> Right-click -> Task-> Restore -> Database.
[image]

2- Go to Timeline then select your time.

[image]