# SQL Server 2012 Rollback changes

Tags: sql-server, rollback, recovery

I have accidentally executed a procedure without `where` clause. Can I get the data back.

The backup of database was taken a week before.

Is there any way to get the data back by using `rollback`.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: **(1)** if you use `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, you can `ROLLBACK` as long as you haven't called `COMMIT` yet, or if that doesn't work **(2)** restore the backup ....

Comment: @marc_s the backup was taken a week before and I want to recover data from today before 11 AM. Will it work?

Comment: Is your database in `full recovery mode`? If it is, perhaps restore from a point in time, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945254/how-to-perform-sql-roll-back-from-transaction-logs

Comment: @IvanSivak yes recovery mode is Full

Comment: @AmmarBukhari good for you :)

Comment: @IvanSivak thank you friend

Comment: @IvanSivak kindly post your comment as answer. I will mark it.

Comment: @AmmarBukhari You're welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from comments. When your database is in [full recovery mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189272.aspx), you can restore your database back to a point in time (thanks to [transaction logs](http://www.sqlshack.com/beginners-guide-sql-server-transaction-logs/)). Therefore, going back before you accidentally executed your sql shouldn't be a problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945254/how-to-perform-sql-roll-back-from-transaction-logs) is nice answer how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

what is your database recovery model?
if recovery model is `full` you can restore database with transaction log backup.
before restoe you should execute backup from your database.

Comment: please check the below link and restore your database to a point in time
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982(v=sql.105).aspx