# restore database to a specific time with old backup and transaction log

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, restore

I have a sample database and I took a backup of that on two weeks ago. Now I wanna restore database to one day ago. I'm using the full recovery model. How can I do this with no extra features (only SSMS - use my old backup and current log)? Maybe I have to re-run my transaction log on the old database backup.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-sql-server-database-to-a-point-in-time-full-recovery-model#TsqlProcedure) but I'm not sure that is my answer or not. Can u explain this exactly for me? Or offer a better way?

Comment: so you have a backup from 2 weeks ago but you want to restore to yesterday?

Comment: @dbatjr yes , i think i can use my current transaction log

Comment: do you have a transaction log from yesterday?

Comment: no , may i can use today log

Comment: a tansaction log backup is just a file of all the changes. If you dont have either a transaction backup or full backup from the time that you need then you can restore to that time

Comment: What is the recovery model of your database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform SQL Roll back from transaction logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945254/how-to-perform-sql-roll-back-from-transaction-logs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i take backup of my current transaction log file , and then i tried to restore database for a specific time with using both old backup and transaction log , and set time plus using replace option . worked correctly!