# How to retrieve the updated column values in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have "Order" table with  more than 5,000 records. When I ran the update query unfortunately I forgot to give the ‘where’ condition. 
Now the Date column in all the records has been updated. Is it possible to retrieve my existing column values.
Example:

```
Update Order 
set ordered = getdate() 
where Cusid=50
```

(here I forget to mention the where condition).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto undo a SQL Server update command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691574/howto-undo-a-sql-server-update-command)

Comment: The thing is I don't have a backup?

Comment: Maybe this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179451.aspx) might help. Why don't you do backups?

Comment: Thats why I alwaysssssssssssssssssssssss wrap my updates and deletes inside a `BEGIN TRAN.... COMMIT TRAN` block.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid NO, cause the update has already been committed. Unless you have a backup of the table it's no more can be undone.